# Confusion in notation related to gradient.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, vector-analysis

I've just started learning vector calculus.

I get to know that gradient of a function $f(x, y)$ is given by,
$$\nabla f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} i + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} j$$

Here $i$ and $j$ are unit vectors.

---

In my pre-calculus course, I was taught that unit vectors are denoted by $\hat i$ , $\hat j$ and $\hat k$ etc. But in the definition of gradient why are they just $i, j , k$?

Comment: It's just a (slightly) different convention. I tend to work in more than $3$ dimensions, so I'd be inclined to call them $e_1$ and $e_2$ instead. They still mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, this is just convention. It is more common, I think, in lower-level math classes (say high school or below), or sometimes in physics, to write the "hat" above the unit vectors in order to remind oneself that they are unit vectors. On the other hand pure mathematicians tend not to care so much as the meaning is understood anyway, and would often instead write $e_1,e_2,\dots$ for the standard basis vectors in arbitrary dimensions. In either case, the notations mean the same thing, and there is absolutely no difference between these.